# Do I have to keep a creeper whenever I draw cards in Fluxx, even if I was drawing cards to give to other players for "Everybody Gets 1"?

Tags: fluxx

Interesting scenario the other day. When playing the Action card "Everybody Gets 1" I drew a Creeper card. At this point though I had a conundrum. The Creeper card states I "must place it face up in front of you as soon as you get it." Well I wasn't "getting" this card, I was going to give it to another player under the rules of "Everybody Gets 1". Under this, the player I give it to should play the Creeper. However the Creeper also states "If you drew it, immediately draw another card to replace it." I did draw the card, so perhaps I should put the Creeper down and continue with the Action card. But it's that they put the word "if" in there that makes me hesitate since the wording makes it sound like only if I receive it, which brings me back to the previous point. So I'm wondering, when playing this Action card do I put down a Creeper if I draw it or does the person I'm giving it to do that?

If people are wondering, when playing the game we've pretty much just gone with whatever ruling feels more appropriate at the time. If someone's feeling generous they put the Creeper down and draw another. If we're feeling more evil, we'll give it to someone else ;) But each time it's come up we're still confused.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After reading the rules carefully, I found that this is mentioned in the Creeper section:

> Note that this is true any time you draw a card; for example, with 'Everybody Gets 1' you must keep all Creepers you get while drawing the cards you'll be giving to other players.

If you drew Creepers during Everybody Gets 1, you would keep the Creepers you got, draw new cards to replace them, and give 1 non-creeper to each other player. After some searching I found it on [the mailing list for Looney Labs](http://lists.looneylabs.com/pipermail/fluxx/2007-October/001075.html). :)

Comment: Ah ha! I apparently missed this while trying to find the answer. Thank ya!